# Disable the data-confirm by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm currently using the gem [data-confirm](https://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal), which normally is working well. But I've upgraded my rails into 5 yesterday, and now I have two modals for the data-confirm. So I would like to how we can remove the default one ?

Comment: I'd try opening an issue on the gem github page

Answer (score 2):

You can override the Rails jQuery UJS handler by:

```
$.rails.confirm = function(){};
```

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/3bff9e049afcb38191c6eb470062b9e51f46e535/src/rails.js#L87